# Find the Bessel Function solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

For positive n, the ordinary differential equation

$$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'+\left(1-\dfrac{n^2}{x^2}\right)y=0$$

has as a solution the Bessel function of order n, $J_n\left(x\right)=x^n\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_kx^k$

Determine $a_1$ by substituing the seris for the Bessel function into the differential equation.

Im unsure of how to determine $a_1$. I have so far
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\left[a_k\left[\left(k+n\right)\left(k+n-1\right)+\left(k+n\right)-n^2\right]+a_{k-2}\right]x^{k+n-2} +\left[a_o\left(n\left(n-1\right)+n-n^2\right)\right]x^{n-2}+\left[a_1\left(n\left(1+n\right)+\left(1+n\right)-n^2\right)\right]x^{n-1}=0$$

For $x^{n-1}$:

$a_1\left(2n+1\right)=0$ so $\Rightarrow n=-\dfrac{1}{2}$

For $x^{k+n-2}$:

$a_k\left[\left(k+n\right)\left(k+n\right)-n^2\right]=-a_{k-2}$

So we have the reccurence relation

$a_k=\dfrac{-a_{k-2}}{k\left(k-1\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

> For $x^{n-1}$ :  $a_1\left(2n+1\right)=0$ so $\Rightarrow n=-\dfrac{1}{2}$

They are some hitchs :

First, do not forget the condition $n>1$ : If not, some terms doesn't exist in your previous equations.

Second, $n$ is an integer and cannot be equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. So the conclusion is simple :
$$a_1=0\qquad \text{in case of } n>1$$

Note : The cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are easy to to treat directly ( No need for using the full series : the first terms are sufficient for a simpler writting) . I don't give all details. You will find this :

Case $n=0$ : $ J_0(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+...$  Thus $a_1=0$ (also obvious because $ J_0(x)$ is an even function).

Case $n=1$ : $J_1(x)=\frac{x}{2}+...$ Thus $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$